# How to open the Google Docs format files with my chrome web store app in google drive UI

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

On the app console, I have set the MIME type and the extension for txt and pdf files. But if I want to support the Google Docs format files, what should I do?

And If I can already open the Google Docs format files, how to convert the files to pdf format when I download them through GOOGLE Drive API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot currently open the Google Docs native formats (Docs, Spreadsheets, Presentations, etc) using the Google Drive SDK. This is something we ([Google](http://google.com)) are looking at fixing.

You are currently limited to exporting them as another format, for example pdf, but this can only be achieved using the [Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_documents_and_files).

Comment: NP, Please get back to us if you have further issues.